# How to configure multisites for the console?

Tags: console

Most of console commands are not listed when using

```
drupal list
```

Drupal Console version 0.11.3

It issues a warning like so:

```
[WARNING] In order to list all of the available commands you should install
       drupal first.
```

Drupal is installed , as multisites.

```
   drupal multi:debug
```

Tells me this error:

```
 [ERROR] There aren't multisites configured
```

How can I configure multisites for the console ?

```
     https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/content/hu/using/how-to-use-drupal-console-in-a-multisite-installation.html
```

EDIT:

a mapping must be done in sites/sites.php for

drupal multisite:debug

to display the list

sites.php

```
 /**
 * Multi-site directory aliasing:
 *
 * Edit the lines below to define directory aliases. Remove the leading hash
 * signs to enable.
 */
$sites = array (
    'my_domain_name.fr'=>'my_folder_name_in_sites?'
);
```

What is the exact format of this array values i dont know

i dont have drupal multi:debug error nomore mais drupal list is still restricted

Answer (score 2):

a mapping must be done in sites/sites.php for

```
   drupal multisite:debug
```

to display the list

sites.php

```
 /**
 * Multi-site directory aliasing:
 *
 * Edit the lines below to define directory aliases. Remove the leading hash
 * signs to enable.
 */
$sites = array (
    'my_domain_name.fr'=>'my_folder_name_in_sites?'
);
```

i am not sure for it to be correctly configured

```
my_folder_name_in_sites?
```

must be

```
my_folder_name
```

or

```
sites/my_folder_name
```

Comment: I think you should mark your own answer as accepted, no?

Comment: well no, coz although drupal multisite:debug do not display error message anymore , i am not sure if what i enter in the site.php is in the correct format , and the drupal list command still display restricted list

Comment: ok, fair enough. But in that case I'd integrate your prior comment in your actual answer also.